# Reduce the number of identical inputs when user is filling out a field

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql

I have a zip table and a city table. Thereby a zip code can have only one city, but a city can have different zip codes. Now the user fills out zip code and city. In the table zip the field city is a foreign key to the table city. Different zip codes should point to only one city name. Here the user can make use of different spellings and I want to avoid that.

These are the possibilities which come to my mind:

- AutoSuggestion ([JQuery Cool Auto-Suggest](http://w3shaman.com/article/jquery-cool-auto-suggest), [AutoSuggest jQuery Plugin](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin), [AutoSuggest v.2.0](http://www.brandspankingnew.net/archive/2006/08/ajax_auto-suggest_auto-complete.html), ...)
- Search similar names in database (with ?)

Do you know any other possibilities?

Comment: This is a great idea, but I do know of some zip codes that have multiple cities. Just a thought to keep in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have them enter the zip code first and then make an AJAX call to get the city automatically.

```
var zip = $('#zip').val();
$.get('http://someurl/get_city_for_zip/' + zip, function (data) {
    // Assuming data is the city:
    $('#city').val(data);
});
```

Comment: I also thought about that but without an AJAX call. I search for the zip code and pre populate the city field if a matching city has been found. I think I'll go with that. Nevertheless I should deal one time with AJAX ...